# Issue with Spring data cassandra due to Spring boot version upgrade to 2.3.1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra, cassandra-driver

Due to the improvements made towards docker image support in 2.3 release of Spring boot, we have decided to migrate to this version. In our project, we are using Cassandra as one of the databases. But it seems that a lot has changed in spring data cassandra, aside from migrating to the cassandra driver verison 4. The issue is this exception that does not let the application start,

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Since you provided explicit contact points, the local DC must be explicitly set (see basic.load-balancing-policy.local-datacenter in the config, or set it programmatically with SessionBuilder.withLocalDatacenter)
```

Now, I have searched online and have found people suggesting:

Add this property to my application.properties:

```
spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter=datacenter1 (in my case since in the exception that it throws, it's mentioned that the local datacenter is - datacenter1)
```

and specify it using while creating CqlSession bean, which I am doing:

```
public CqlSession session() {

     String containerIpAddress = getContactPoints();
     int containerPort = getPort();
     InetSocketAddress containerEndPoint = new InetSocketAddress(containerIpAddress, containerPort);

    return CqlSession.builder().withLocalDatacenter(getLocalDataCenter())
            .addContactPoint(containerEndPoint)
            .withAuthCredentials(dbProperties.getCassandraUserName(), dbProperties.getCassandraPassword())
            .withKeyspace(getKeyspaceName()).build(); }
```

But I am still stuck and not able to start up the application. How can this issue be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Reactive Cassandra, but it's mostly the same. The datacenter field, which is new, can be found by logging into your cassandra instance and running the

```
select data_center from system.local;
```

As for my configuration, it looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories
public class CassandraConfig {

  @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.contact-points}")
  private String hostList;

  @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.datacenter}")
  private String datacenter;

  @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name}")
  private String keyspaceName;

  @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.username}")
  private String userName;

  @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.password}")
  private String password;

  @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.port}")
  private Integer port;

  @Bean
  public CqlSessionFactoryBean getCqlSession() {
    CqlSessionFactoryBean factory = new CqlSessionFactoryBean();
    factory.setUsername(userName);
    factory.setPassword(password);
    factory.setPort(port);
    factory.setKeyspaceName(keyspaceName);
    factory.setContactPoints(hostList);
    factory.setLocalDatacenter(datacenter);
    return factory;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me using this configuration

```
public CqlSession session() {
        return CqlSession.builder().withLocalDatacenter(getLocalDataCenter())
                .addContactPoint(InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved(getContactPoints(), 9042))
                //.withAuthCredentials(dbProperties.getCassandraUserName(), dbProperties.getCassandraPassword())
                .withKeyspace(getKeyspaceName()).build();
    }


@Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public CassandraTemplate cassandraTemplate(CqlSession session) throws Exception {
        return new CassandraTemplate(session);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a different config needed for Apache Cassandra to truly work with the new spring versions. It took me about 50 hours of searching before finding this out on this documentation - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#cassandra.cassandra-java-config

You'll need to create a new config file as specified there. To do this, follow thus:

Create a new package named `config`
Create a .java class file in the package named - `CassandraConfig`
Copy and paste the below code into it.

```
@Configuration public class CassandraConfig { public @Bean CqlSession session() { return CqlSession.builder().withKeyspace("mykeyspacename").build(); } }
```

Note, change the Keyspace name to your Keyspace name defined in your property file. If you have not created a Keyspace, start Cassandra server on your system, login to the `cqlsh` on the terminal or cmd by issuing `cqlsh`, and issue this command -

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS mykeyspacename WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 } AND DURABLE_WRITES = true ;
```

By now, when you start the spring boot app, it should run without any error.